# Can we provide the navigation to different parts of a single image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

We are developing an Android application where the requirement is to have single image having different navigation when the different parts of the image are clicked. E.g. A full image of a building and clicking on the different flats we want to show the amenities offered in the flat ( build up area, number of rooms, number of balconies, terrace (if pent house) etc).

Have thought the following two possibilities,

1. Slice the images and put together (such that it look as a single image) in layout xml, once user clicks it, with the image view id we will know which portion is clicked.
2. Slice the images and put together (such that it look as a single image) in html with onclick event, load the html in webview, create JavaScript class that handles clicks.

With above two it is difficult because the parts are not proper rectangle or square shaped.

ASP.Net has ImageMap control for this purpose, do we have anything of that sort in Android?

Comment: you can try with the swipe views ?https://github.com/chiuki/android-swipe-image-viewer and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994129/android-swipe-images

Comment: Create a class which is having a Point and Bitmap member values, create as many instance of that class accordance with the image what you have. Now crate the Your ImageView by extending View or SurfaceView and on draw method you draw all these instances Bitamp over the canvas based on the Point.Now onTouch method in your View get the x and y co-ordinate and find which of these instances is having this point. You can form the Rectangle of the instance using the Point and Bitmap size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such component to do this in android, but you can easily create one:

```
public class ImageMap extends ImageView implements onClickListener 
{

  List<Rect> hotspot;

  public ImageMap(Context c)
  {
    super(c);
    hotspot = new List<Rect>();
    setOnClickListener(this);
  }

public void addHotSpot(Rect r)
{
   hotspots.add(r);
}


  public void onClick(Event e)
  {
     int currentPosition = 0;
     for(Rect spot : hotspot){
       if(spot.contains(e.getX(), e.getY()))
            triggerClickInHotSpotAtPos(currentPosition);
       currentPosition ++;
     }

  }

  public void triggerHotSpot(int hotspotIndex)
  {
   //TODO  do something useful like calling listener for this given hotspot etc ...
  }
}
```

be aware that is not a finished work, but its more like pseudo code, the important is you got the idea.

Comment: To be more complete and flexible you can even extends only the onClickistener to do the same job in the onclickmethod. This way you can attach such listener to any views ...

Comment: Hi Guian, thank you so much for the answer. my question is, when I call addHotSpot(Rect r) how would I define the exact x,y & height, width of the rectangles representing different portions of my image?

Comment: well... I guees it should be set as arbitrary values, based on your image content and the hotspot you need. In your case it should be the coordinates of the displayed flat on the building picture. I'm not sure I got what you meant...

Comment: Is there any tool which can give me the coordinates of the hotspot of my selection? also, would those coordinates hold good on different screen sizes & densities?

Comment: I suggeset you take measures from the source image with a design tool like photoshop. Coordinates should be good for any screen. What you should care about is if you apply any scale to the image, hotspot Rect have to be scaled the same way.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a single ImageView by tapping into its [onTouch event handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29).

See the [MotionEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) documentation for specifics on how to get coordinates of the touch event.

Comment: Hi Matt Mayers, thanks for the answer. My question is, how would I define the current tapped coordinates fall under which portion of my image?